# how does the Entry widget in tkinter work?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm still a beginner with Tkinter and I'm not quite sure how the Entry widget work. I can't seem to get the value I enter I tried binding the root window to this function but I can't figure out why it's not working.

```
def get_value(event):
current_obj = root.focus_get()
if (current_obj in entries):
    text = current_obj.get()
    data.append(text)
```

Comment: How are you calling `get_value`? Please show the code that sets up the binding. Also, how do you know it's not working? Have you examined the contents of `text` immediately after calling the `get()` method?

Comment: sort.bind('<Button-1>',get_entries)

Comment: I don't know exactly what was wrong but when I examined text it was always empty

Comment: sort is a frame of entries. the app I'm working on is very simple it sort a given table but I had trouble getting the values from the user

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` to get the value from the entry.

First you define the entry like this:
    e = tk.Entry()
    e.pack()

Then you can have a static function which gets the value of the entry by calling `entry.get()`

```
def get_entry_value(entry)
    entry.get()
```

Alternatively, if you have multiple entries in your app which are all contained in some iterable:

```
def get_entries(self, event=None):
    data = list()
    for e in self.entries:
        data.append(e.get())
    return data
```

Comment: much appreciated, I'll try it

Comment: Be sure to approve the answer so that everyone with the same problem can find the solution @asma :)